# MVVM Light Messenger executing multiple times

Tags: mvvm-light

I am using MVVM Light and am using Messages to communicate between ViewModels to let a ViewModel know when it is ok to execute something.  My problem is that I register for a message and then it receives it multiple times.  so to keep from my program executing something more than once I have to create boolean flags to see if it has already been recieved.  Any idea why it does this and how I can stop it?

Comment: Where is your message being sent? Have you stepped through the MVVM Light source to find out why the message is being sent multiple times? There's a certain amount of work you can do, or more detail you can provide, before your question can be answered.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you unregister your message handlers once you do not need them anymore. The Messenger keeps a reference to the registered methods and this prevents them from being garbage collected.

Therefore, for ViewModels: make sure that you call Cleanup once you done (or implement IDisposable and call Cleanup from there).

For Views (Controls, Windows, or similar) call Messenger.Unregister in an event that occurs on the teardown of the view, e.g. the Unloaded event.

This is a known behaviour of the MVVM and has been discussed in several places.

Comment: ... except that in WPF, the UserControl.Unloaded event is not guaranteed to be fired, as per http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/575287/the-usercontrol-unloaded-event-is-not-raised-when-the-mainwindow-gets-closed - so it's not that easy.

Comment: The point I am making is that you have to clean up behind the Messenger, otherwise, it will keep processing messages although it should no longer do so. The Unloaded event is one place, but it might not be the only or the best.

Comment: Unregister sample code -  Messenger.Default.Unregister<NotificationMessage<TemplateSelectedForActionPayLoad>>
                    (
                        this,
                        NotificationReceivedWithTemplateSelection
                    );

Comment: Simpler:`Messenger.Default.Unregister(this)` - ungeisters all messages associated with `this`.

Answer (score 7):

Very old question but I solved the problem by doing this:

`static bool isRegistered = false;`

and then, in the constructor:

```
if( !isRegistered )
{
   Messenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(this, OnMessageReceived);
   isRegisterd = true;
}
```

Comment: This is the likely fix for the problem, and do not register the Messenger in the constructor.

Comment: Although this prevents double registration, it does not ensure that the message is processed by the right instance. Or that an instance is not kept alive by the registration.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue before. It had to do with the Messenger.Default.Register being called more than once.  The MVVMLight Messenger class will register the same item 'x' number of times.  This is why when you call the Send you get it many times.

Anyone know how to prevent MVVMLight from registering multiple times?

Comment: I found for my issue at least it was because other view models and views were haning around in memory.  I am still having one issue where I need to send a message from vm to a view.  My problem now is that all previous instances of this view are still in memory so the message gets sent and recieved multiple times

Answer (score 1):

really old but thought I would answer just in case somebody needs it.  I was fairly new to silverlight at the time and the issue ended up being a memory leak as the viewModel, which had multiple instances, was still in memory.

Answer (score 0):

As other contributors mentioned, the same message is being registered multiple times. I have noticed this behavior taking place while navigating to View X then navigating back to View Z where the message is registered in the constructor of the Z ViewModel. One solution is to set the [NavigationCacheMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationcachemode) property to Required

```
<Page
  ........
  ........
  NavigationCacheMode="Required">
```