# In MVVM, does hooking a model item's event in the ViewModel cause a memory leak?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, memory-leaks, event-handling

Trying to track down some memory leaks in our WPF/MVVM app and something occurred to me...

If you listen to ModelItem events in its associated ViewModel with an instance-specific handler, doesn’t that make the ViewModel hang around as long as the ModelItem still exists?

Consider this case...

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel(ModelItem item)
    {
        this.Item = item;
        item.SomeEvent += ItemSomeEventHandler
    }

    Public ModelItem Item { get; private set; }

    // Note: This is a handler on this instance, not a shared handler
    private void ItemSomeEventHandler(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(“The model changed!”);
    }
}
```

If this does cause a leak, how/where do you unhook it?  You can't do it in 'Dispose' since that won't be called if something still has a reference to it, which it looks like it does: the model item.

Would the proper place be to implement Dispose in the control where this ViewModel is used, then trickle down an event-unhook routine there?  Seems a bit treacherous to rely on something  external to make sure you clean up your own internal, but short of going to an EventManager architecture, I'm not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will cause a leak.. or more specifically the `ItemViewModel` will not be collected when the view is no longer displayed since the `ModelItem` holds a reference to the `ItemViewModel`

You could implement `Dispose` and unhook the eventhandler which is perfectly valid if you can control the lifecycle of the `ViewModel`. The question is what component is creating the `ItemViewModel`? If it is another view model then you can delegate the dispose to that or if the view creates the view model then you can have the call the `Dispose` method.

However if you use like the `MVVMLight` toolkit then you can use its `ICleanup` interface instead or something similar. Check this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7037282/373706) out for more info.

Comment: Our ItemViewModel classes are managed by a root ControlViewModel (e.g. ListBoxViewModel would manage ListItemViewModels which are bound to a list of ModelItems.)  We can control when the root VM unloads with the UI so I guess we just have to tell it to unhook all its child ViewModelItem objects' event listeners. (So much for the GC pattern being better for memory than ref counting! Swapped one problem for another!)

Comment: Well the GC is for managed resources. You _could_ argue that event handlers is not _managed_ since you have to explicitly unhook if you want it collected unless both the publisher and subscriber is up for collection.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [WeakEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) / [DelegateCommands](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/353774)?

They implement weak references to delegates that does not need deterministic detatchment.

Comment: That's the direction we're going for our own rolled events, but it's frustrating that we have to set that up for all existing objects' events (e.g. ObservableCollection, etc.)

Comment: Fotr eprecisely same reason, weak events \ weak comamnds should be implemented by design in MVVM. MVVM discourages event driven architecture. It encourages command driven architecture that too in weak manner.

Comment: But how is there a command in a command-driven architecture when dealing with something like an observable collection? You want your ViewModel to automatically update when the model changes, but any number of places can change the model, including non-command ways.